# Authenticate a user with my own function/api?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

When user submits login form, for authenticating that user instead of using cakephp default authentication `$this->Auth->login()` I want to call some java based api where I will send user id and password entered by user and that api will return user details if user is authentic and false if not. I want to use cakephp AuthComponent for rest of thing (for example: sessions etc) but just for authenticating a user I want to call my api. Is this possible ? can I override some core method ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm no CakePHP expert but I would think you'd be able to populate/create the Auth object manually based on what you get back from the API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this covers it, under "Creating Custom Authentication Objects"

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class extending `BaseAuthenticate` in `Controllers/Component/Auth` folder path. There you have to implement an `authenticate()` method that, if logged successfully, have to return an array with user data, and if not, return false.

Then you tell `Auth` component to use your custom authenticate when you call it in AppController by:

```
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
        'yourNewAuth' => array(
            //other stuff
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I created the authenticate class. It's working fine if I return user details array but in case of FALSE(i.e. user not found), cakephp ignores that and logs the user in(ignoring my class), although it should show error.

Comment: looks like, cakephp running its own default authenticate function after running mine. how can i fix this\?

Answer (score 0):

you can set **AuthComponent::$sessionKey** to false to ensure AuthComponent doesn’t try to read user info from session.

http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-AuthComponent.html